# Rails console runs without prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, jruby

When I run my rails console I got something like this:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
/Users/sebastiannowak/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7@global/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler.rb:254 warning: shadowing outer local variable - path
Switch to inspect mode.
Time.now
Time.now
2012-06-27 09:27:21 +0200
```

As you can see I can interact with console but it is quite uncomfortable. I run JRuby 1.6.7. Somebody has such issue?

Comment: This happens to me, but only if I run with `--ng` (connect to nailgun). `JRUBY_OPTS=' ' irb` gives me the prompt, and `:PROMPT_MODE` is `:DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most probably somewhere in you `~/.irbrc`, you're doing:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :XMP
```

Try removing that line. Or change it to:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
```

Comment: Wow, man! Thank you so much. In ~/.irbrc I haven't any line with prompt mode settings.

Comment: Thank you! I came across the same problem and this solved it.

Answer (score 3):

On newer version of JRuby, the Rails console has a variety of other problems for me as well:

- Command duplicated on the next line
- Multiple Enter keypresses needed to exit
- First command doesn't show while typing

Running the console with the following fixed it for me:

```
jruby -Xlaunch.inproc=true -S rails c
```