# rails console fails with `Switch to inspect mode` in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, irb

I create a rails project by `rails new foo`, then `cd foo`, and run `rails c`.

Then I got message like this.

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.2)
Switch to inspect mode.
```

That's all. I can't use rails console.

Have you any idea what am I doing wrong?

I'm using `railsinstaller` with ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 both, and `ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]` from Rubyinstaller. All versions fails with same error.

There is no problem with simple `irb` command.

#### Edit

By following Graeme's advice, I updated `rb-readline` from `0.5.0` to `0.5.1`. and uninstalled old one.

```
$ gem list | grep rb-readline
rb-readline (0.5.1)
```

But the message remains same.

Comment: Do you have `rb-readline` gem?  And if so what version?

Comment: I have `rb-readline (0.5.0)` with `ruby 2.0.0p195` in Railsinstaller.

Comment: Probably related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221345/rails-console-runs-without-prompt

Answer (score 42):

In case anyone gets this error with Docker, I got it because I ran `docker run rails` but needed `-it`.

```
> docker run rails
Switch to inspect mode. # fail
> docker run -it rails
irb(main):001:0> # yay
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with docker-compose?

Comment: Here's an alias to dive into the rails console on a running machine (including a machine you started with dockre-compose) `function dbrailsc { docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep app_name| awk '{print $1;}') bundle exec rails c; }
` (you have to replace app_name with the name of the rails machine in your docker-compose.yml)

Comment: Happened to me too when running `docker exec container_name rails c` instead of `docker exec -it container_name rails c`

Comment: I ran into this issue multiple times now, and for me, it was because the command to actually start the server (`foreman start`) was commented out of my `docker-compose.yml` so it didn't know what to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem caused by the `rb-readline` gem in version 0.5.0.  It has been subsequently fixed in 0.5.1 which came out a few months ago.

You should therefore upgrade the `rb-readline` gem to v0.5.1 to fix this problem.

You can see here more details about the [issue](https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline/issues/84) and the [resolution](https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline/pull/95).

Comment: Thanks for advice, but after updating I still have same error.

Comment: Updating should have fixed the DL deprecated warning but not the automatic switch to inspect mode.  Do you have a .irbrc file in your home directory?

Comment: DL deprecated warning still remains. And I don't have `.irbrc` in my home directory. I have had the file, but I already removed, because it caused another `rails console`'s error.

Comment: Back then, the problem was solved once, but now I run into similar problem. The answer is no, I can't type commands into the console. Just after the message, it return to command line.

Comment: It's year 2015, the same error in Rails 5.0 on Windows 10 the Rails console command produces
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1) Switch to inspect mode.
no prompt
It is a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

In docker-compose.yaml, add `command: sleep infinity` under ruby-part seems work.
inspired by [this](https://gist.github.com/schacon/67a278cfa7853d5d47b46785190820d0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).