# ruby on rails console isn't working, I am getting"Switch to inspect mode" on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I run my rails console it is saying "Switch to inspect mode" .I am working on windows . Kindly help !

Comment: Could you give some more information about the environment you are running, what command you are running, and what the error message says exactly? Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23578440/rails-console-fails-with-switch-to-inspect-mode-in-windows

Comment: """ $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
Switch to inspect mode.  """"       
         This is the line which is coming and nothing is coming after that ,let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the terminal you're using, not the console itself. (Which terminal are you using...?) Try running `$ irb` and seeing if you're getting the same issue.

I had the same issue a while back, and momentarily fixed it by changing the irb config output mode, but it still tended to break elsewhere. I recommend using ConEmu to permanently squash the annoyance.

Comment: I am pretty new to this business,so could you let me know how to make out of the terminal . I will get back to you .