# prevent each from returning all the data in rails c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

Many times in administering rails web applications, I find myself developing methods that I want to call from `rails console` since they are designed to solve specific problems and so they usually don't deserve a place in the administrative area.

Suppose that i've a method that returns an array of data. 
I want to perform some operation on each one.

```
1.9.3 >  x = [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
1.9.3 > x.each() do |x|; puts x; end
1
2
3
4
5
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The last line is the one that i want to skip. 
Thats because actually the array is of Model objects having many fields and the elements are several tens.
So the unneeded repetition of what my input has been, has the effect of scrolling the console by thousand of lines with the result of hiding the log of my operation.

I tried with for - in loop hoping that it didn't return the value, but it do so too. 
This is sort of trivial issue, but it's seriously impairing my rails-c-based administrative approach. 
Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: Quirk-mode: `x.each() do |x|; puts x; end && false`. I know it’s an ugly hack but I think it may help you to schieve what you wanted.

Comment: Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221345/rails-console-runs-without-prompt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?:

```
$> rails c
=> Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
=> [1,2,3,4].each { |x| puts x };nil
#> 1
#> 2
#> 3
#> 4
#> nil
```

Comment: ok, i get the trick and just feel stupid not to have thought of it :-)